Correlation (scatter) plot between two groups in the same time series in R
I am struggling with making a scatter plot and then performing a cross-correlation between my two groups; vitamin_intake and diffusion, across a time series. Note both groups have the same time series.
For example, see below data table.



Time
Vitamin_rep1
Vitamin_rep2
Diffusion_rep1
Diffusion_rep2




1
0.025518341
0.019979193
0.048
0.056


2
0.045188729
0.002983554
0.0285
0.072


3
0.003721425
0.010350122
0.047
0.084


4
0.005316321
0.002091164
0.063
0.055


5
0.023923445
0.013849514
0.023
0.043



I have been trying to get a scatter plot with each of these replicates, x = vitamins, and y = diffusion, and then trying to a cross-correlation with a linear regression.
Please let me know if this is possible or not.
So far, I have struggled with the grouping of these.
Thanks

Hi KenH. Please update the question to include the code you've tried so far.

If the data are pivoted, you can get a plot of Diffusion vs Vitamin for rep1 and rep2. I made some intermediate data frame so you can see what each step does. Is the result what you are after? I also added linear fits of each rep. I don't know what you meant by "a cross-correlation with a linear regression".
library(tidyverse)
DF <- read.csv("~/R/Play/Dummy.csv")
DFlng <- DF |> pivot_longer(cols = -Time, names_to = c("Type", "rep"), names_sep = "_")
DFlng2 <- DFlng |> pivot_wider(names_from = "Type", values_from = "value")  
ggplot(DFlng2, aes(x = Vitamin, y = Diffusion, color = rep, group = rep)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


Created on 2024-11-07 with reprex v2.1.1

And how would you add one linear regression line to this?

Also, thank you so much! This really helped me, and I was able to get it to work. Thanks so much.

Is it possible to group the colours and add two linear regression lines for "vitamin" column, and "diffusion" column? Using maybe group = interaction(vitamin, diffusion) within the aes(_____) function?

You can add a regression line for all the data by adding a geom_smooth() with its own aes() and no group aesthetic. The parameter inherit.aes can be useful to avoid inheriting the group=rep from ggplot(). It doesn't make sense to have a regression line for only vitamin or diffusion if the plot is Diffusion vs. Vitamin. You could get a regression of those individually vs. Time.  Please edit your original question to clarify what you want. And show some code where you try to achieve that.
